# Which ones are correct? "At latest" vs "at the latest"

Tags: phrases, expressions

Had a discussion with a friend:

In their (foreign) online dictionary, it defines 'at the latest' with parentheses around the article, rendering it optional. In all English dictionaries I found it considers the article non-optional. (Or at least it doesn't specify them as optional) The entry in the foreign dictionary made her confident in always writing down 'at latest' when specifying the very latest time at which something could take place. I felt it sounded a bit like news headlines where they often 'compress' the text, and thought the article should be mandatory.

So of these two options, which ones are correct?

"She should be home at ten o'clock at the latest."

"She should be home at ten o'clock at latest."

If hers is incorrect, sources or explanations would be appreciated, as I don't think she'd be convinced by just showing another dictionary not showing the article as optional.

Comment: Hello, ZS. (a) I'd say that the deleted form is quite to very formal (but certainly not 'incorrect'). (b) Perhaps an example from an article by linguists [Perfetti Zhang and Berent, in _Orthography, Phonology, Morphology and Meaning_
edited by R. Frost, Marian Katz](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ai9pVimnMn0C&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=%22at+latest%22+meaning&source=bl&ots=qg-qnVjg1C&sig=ACfU3U3R7y1zaPpVNd3cyiCV6dicLdB5YQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_-tSm7dnjAhW_VRUIHX9-DIo4ChDoATADegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=%22at%20latest%22%20meaning&f=false) ("We are tempted to suggest that ...

Comment: phonological activation occurs, at latest, at the point of activation.... This suggestion is better  captured by the phrase 'at-lexically' ...") adequately demonstrates acceptability (but also hints strongly at a degree of rarefiedness). // Dictionaries cannot be comprehensive. Some are more helpful than others; at least the dictionary your friend used showed the availability of the alternative phrase. But whether they're totally interchangeable in every context is a different matter. / ' ... at the latest' is what I'd expect in everyday conversation....

Comment: Which is what [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+latest%2Cat+the+latest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20latest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20latest%3B%2Cc0) seem to suggest (though domain-sampling would be required to back up my 'register-influenced' claim).